# buffered - UE: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

Function causes an error in the browser chrome, how to treat?

http://jsfiddle.net/6QaWc/

```
Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 
pu 
(anonymous function) 
jQuery.event.dispatch
elemData.handle
```

I would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: i just fell asleep while listening to the traack.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're trying to activate the objects before they are ready to be used.

If I wrap part of your code in the 'loadeddata' event:

```
$(mme).bind('loadeddata', function() { 
    console.log("Data is loaded...");
    gp(); 
    setTimeout(function () {
        gt();
    }, 2500);
});
```

the error goes away. Now, I'm not sure if this works the way you want it to, because I noticed some strange behavior in how the progress meter works after that, but maybe that will give you a nudge in the right direction to pursue a working solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/6QaWc/16/

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but in your example does not work file load indicator . But I need it.

Comment: Well, the above eliminates the error. You need to work from there to figure out how to get what you need... there are other events that are triggered in the lifecycle of the audio object.